# Converting hexadecimal value to decimal in Python

Tags: python

I just started working with hexadecimal values in python and am a bit surprised with what I just encountered. I expected the following code to first print a hexadecimal string, and then a decimal value.

Input:

```
n = 0x8F033CAE74F88BA10D2BEA35FFB0EDD3
print('Hex value for n is:', n)
print('Dec value for n is:', int(str(n), 16))
```

Output:

> Hex value for n is: 190096411054295805012706659640261275091
>
> Dec value for n is: 8921116140846515089057635273465667902228615313

How is it possible that 2 different different numbers are shown? I expected the first number to be a hexadecimal string and the second it's decimal equivalent, what is this second value in this case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`0x` is a way to input an integer with an hexadecimal notation.

```
>>> n = 0x8F033CAE74F88BA10D2BEA35FFB0EDD3
```

This hexadecimal notation is forgotten directly after instantiation, though:

```
>>> n
190096411054295805012706659640261275091
>>> str(n)
'190096411054295805012706659640261275091'
```

So when you call `int(str(n), 16)`, Python interprets `'190096411054295805012706659640261275091'` as an hexadecimal number:

```
>>> int(str(n), 16)
8921116140846515089057635273465667902228615313
```

You need to input the original hex string:

```
>>> int("8F033CAE74F88BA10D2BEA35FFB0EDD3", 16)
190096411054295805012706659640261275091
```

or use [`hex`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hex):

```
>>> int(hex(n), 16)
190096411054295805012706659640261275091
```

Comment: Thus, I guess, the second output is the decimal, interpreted as hexadecimal (digit by digit), and converted back to decimal. Hence the even bigger number. Am I right?

Comment: @Scheff: Exactly.

Comment: I tried to reproduce on my calculator but the numbers have to many digits... ;-)